# Image display in react native android app

Tags: android, reactjs, image, native

I am looking for solution to display image from a url.  I am hard coding the url in my source code but want to keep changing the image associated with the url.
is it possible guys?
thank you

Comment: Put some code here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The easiest way is to add a query string after url. It also works for both iOS and android:

```
<Image
style={styles.yourImageStyle}
source={uri: this.state.yourPhotoURL + '?' + new Date()}
/>
```

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: thank you bro, but I guess I needed to mention that the image link is coming from a image host like 'IMGUR'. I am hosting my image on  'IMGUR' so the link will be different every time I change the image. but obviously I cant keep changing the link in the app code everytime.

Comment: @Speedy11: Your welcome bro, Have you ever test this code? 

<Image source={{uri: <your_image_uri>, CACHE: 'reload'}} />
Can you also put your code here? In this way I can help you better.